# Ionic2 build demos not working

Tags: ionic2

I want to build the demos from the forked Ionic 2 repository. when I run `'gulp demos.build'` 
I get the following errors on my terminal:

```
ERRROR:  Command failed: node --max_old_space_size=8096 /Users/luki/Applications/ionic-fork/ionic/node_modules/.bin/ngc -p /Users/luki/Applications/ionic-fork/ionic/demos/tsconfig.json
Error: Error at /Users/luki/Applications/ionic-fork/ionic/node_modules/@types/protractor/index.d.ts:22:27: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'IButton'.
Error at /Users/luki/Applications/ionic-fork/ionic/node_modules/@types/protractor/index.d.ts:25:24: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'IKey'.
Error at /Users/luki/Applications/ionic-fork/ionic/node_modules/@types/protractor/index.d.ts:28:45: Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'typeof error'.
```

I installed 'typings install selenium-webdriver but it doesn't help. Maybe some other typings are missing ...

Anybody got a clue about this ?